# How to json marshal a int type value to null

Tags: go

because of the go has defalut value of int type, so if I defined a int type, and push it into the struct/map/slice... then `j, _ := json.Marshal(resource)`, it will be the `0`.
Is there has any way to make it into `null` in json string?

for example:

```
    var a int
    b := []int{a, 1, 2}
    s, _ := json.Marshal(b)
```

My expect output of `string(s)` is `[null, 1, 2]`

Comment: `a` isn't null. It's value is 0.

Comment: What output would you expect for `[]int{0, 1, 2}`?

Comment: *"Is there has any way to make it into null in json string?"* -- No, not with the builtin `int` type. You'd have to use a different type that can be a Go `nil` (e.g `*int`, or `interface{}`). Or you need to define your own type that knows that the value `0` should be turned into `null` when marshaled into json (by implementing the json.Unmarshaler interface).

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this would be to use `*int` instead of `int`,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func createIntPtr(x int) *int {
    return &x
}

func main() {
    var a *int
    b := []*int{a, createIntPtr(1), createIntPtr(2)}
    s, _ := json.Marshal(b)
    fmt.Println(string(s))
}
```

Output: `[null,1,2]`

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qnLjsx35p82

`*int` would be better suited as its default value is `nil`.
So, when it gets marshalled to json it becomes null, just like you expect.

The helper function `createIntPtr` is just a convenient way to add integer literals to the integer pointer array as Go doesn't allow to take the address of an integer constant.